# How to solve re-save saved layer problem using LeafletJS

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson

I have a problem at LeafletJS. I have a save button. If I click this our drawn layers transfer to a feature group. But if I add new polygon and save it it also saves what it has previously recorded. How I can solve this problem ?

Screenshots for better understanding:
[image]

[image]

my codes:

```
var fgroup = new L.featureGroup();

map.on('pm:create', e => {
    var layer = e.layer;
    var layerType = e.shape;
    layer.options = {
        pmIgnore: false  //true ıdı sen kapattın cok delık acabılmek için
    } 
    if (layerType == "Polygon" || layerType == "Poly" || layerType == "Rectangle") {
        fgroup.addLayer(layer);
        
    }
    if (layerType == "Polygon" || layerType == "Poly" || layerType == "Rectangle") {
        layer2 = layer;
          popupbranch = L.popup()
            .setLatLng(layer.getCenter())
            .setContent('<div id="branchAreaSave"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="branchAreaSaveButton">SubeEkle</button></div>')
            .openOn(map);
    }
    if (layerType == "Marker") { 
        markerCoords = [layer.getLatLng().lng, layer.getLatLng().lat];
        markerLayer = layer.toGeoJSON(); 
        console.log(markerCoords); 
        // layer.remove();  marker'ı siliyor
        map.pm.disableDraw('Marker');
    }
});


$(document).on("click", "#btnSavePolygons", function () {   
    map.removeLayer(fgroup); 
    var geo = {};
    var testPolygon = []; 
    fgroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer.toGeoJSON().type == "Feature") {
            console.log("Feature");
            console.log(layer.toGeoJSON()); 
            testPolygon.push(layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates);
        } 
        
    }); 
    if (testPolygon.length == 1) {
        geo.type = "Polygon";
        geo.coordinates = testPolygon; 
    }
    else {
        geo.type = "MultiPolygon";
        geo.coordinates = testPolygon;  
    } 
   
});
```

Comment: In your saving procedure you are removing `fgroup` layer from the map with `map.removeLayer(fgroup);` call. When do you add this layer to the map?

Comment: @TomazicM I added this part  `if (layerType == "Polygon" || layerType == "Poly" || layerType == "Rectangle") {
        fgroup.addLayer(layer);
        
    }`

Comment: I'm not asking about that, I'm asking when you add layer `fgroup` to the map?

Comment: Since I am new to this subject, I am missing some terms. I think I'm missing the use of the features you mentioned. I guess I need to do some more research on how to use them. Thanks for getting back to my previous questions and this @TomazicM

Comment: Anyway, I think that instead of `map.removeLayer(fgroup);` you should use `fgroup.clearLayers()`.

Comment: Thank you so much it's working. I got the result I wanted

Comment: I'll put this into answer, so it may help somebody else with similar question/problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `fgroup` feature group layer just for storing newly drawn items. It's never added to the map, so statement `map.removeLayer(fgroup)`, with which you probably want to clear layer content, makes no sense.

To remove all existing features from the group layer, you have to use `.clearLayers()` method:

```
fgroup.clearLayers();
```